# libstdc++-6.dll not found when using minGW with VSCode to run simple C++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

I am working in C++ for the first time and running into issues compiling multiple files. The issue appears to be related to the compiler being unable to find the libstdc++-6.dll file even though it is present in the minGW bin directory which is linked to in PATH. I am looking for help identifying why.

I wrote a basic main function that has both cout and cin, which compiles and runs as expected. However, when I add an additional basic class header file and an implementation file as well as add `#include "className.h"` at the top of the file with the main function, it behaves badly. When I Run Build Task, it builds an exe, but does not call either the cout or cin. If I then run the .exe on the external command prompt I get the following error:

[image]

I found several SO threads where this problem was solved by moving the libstdc++-6.dll into the directory containing the .exe. I copied and pasted the file from the minGW bin directory and that works. However, I would expect the compiler to find this file by itself and am wondering if there is some obvious reason why it would not find it.

I have several peers who followed the exact steps I did and their systems are picking up this file, so it seems it must be something that is misconfigured on mine. The .h and .cpp files I added have been thoroughly tested on other systems and are not the problem.

(I am using a PC with a windows 10 operating system, minGW 8.0.0, and VSCode 1.49.3, the last two were freshly installed today)

Comment: Try to search answer on SO typing the _ZNSt7_cxx1112... There is a ton of exact such questions on SO.

Comment: I have which is how I found the dll that was missing and was able to test if adding it fixed the issue. The other SO threads I have seen on this ask the user to add the dll. I want to know if there's a way I can run these *without* adding it in the directory every time.

Comment: Look at @Saralyn' answer, it's correct. The same answers are in the similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this was happening to me was because I had another software installed that was also using the libstdc++-6.dll file. This software has a shorter path to the file than mine so it was getting picked up instead.

The steps I took to fix this were:

1. Use search on the file explorer to find all the places where this file exists.
2. Move the other files to location with a longer path name.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is exactly what was happening to me. I typed `where libstdc++-6.dll` into Command Prompt to find out where the conflicting path was coming from.

Answer (score -2):

change from this `#include <iostream>` to this `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` this worked for me I am using VS Code with Mingw compiler and it fixed libstdc++-6.dll error.

Comment: Please read this: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073) Then consider editing and improving your answer.